# With lots of help, I have gotten this android class activity down to only one error. Eclipse ask me to add ")" ,"}", and ";" why though?

Tags: android

```
package com.android.drinksonme;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Screen2 extends Activity {

    // Declare our Views, so we can access them later
    private EditText etUsername;
    private EditText etPassword;
    private Button btnLogin;
    private Button btnSignUp;
    private TextView lblResult;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Get the EditText and Button References
                etUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
                etPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
                btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
                btnSignUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signup_button);
                lblResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

                       btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener () {  
                           public void onClick(View v){
                            final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
                            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

                           if(username.equals("test") && password.equals("test")){
                               Intent i = new Intent(Screen2.this, DrinksTwitter.class);
                               startActivity(i);} 
                           else
                               lblResult.setText("Invalid username or password."); } 

                         /*  final Intent k = new Intent(Screen2.this, SignUp.class);
                           btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                               public void onClick(View v) { 
                                   startActivity(k);
                               }*/ 
                           }
                       );
                    }                   
                   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
(new OnClickListener () {
    if( blah blah
```

It must be something like:

```
(new OnClickListener () {
    public void onClick(View v){
        if( blah blah
    }
});
```

With regards to your new error... what about this:

```
               btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener () { 
                   public void onClick(View v){
                       String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
                       String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
                       if(username.equals("test") && password.equals("test")){
                           Intent i = new Intent(Screen2.this, DrinksTwitter.class);
                           startActivity(i);
                       } 
                       else
                           lblResult.setText("Invalid username or password.");
                       } 
                   }
               );
```

Comment: is there an example of a log in screen on the net anywhere !!! i just keep creating more errors!!

Comment: changed the code (see above), i get no errors, but now whenever "login" is clicked in the app, it always says the username or password is invalid.

Comment: I also edited my answer. You will have to change the declaration of `etUsername` and `etPassword` to be final, or it will give you a compile error. The problem is that you were setting the value of the strings before the onClick method is executed.

Comment: Ok, I tried that but it simply crashes out now when i enter "test" and "test" as the login credentials. I have a book, but there are no examples that help.... :-(

Comment: Paste the logcat after it crashes

Answer (score 1):

One compile error is meaningless. If you fix that error, it could be hiding hundreds.

But you're missing a curly brace. Go through and make sure all your curly braces are matched correctly.

*Edit*:

To your updated code, now your

```
String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
```

are being defined when you create the click listener. ie before oncreate is finished and before the user can possibly enter anything.

Comment: adding  curly brace to the end just creates another error on the second to last curly brace line

Comment: I never said to add one at the end. Go through and make sure they're matched CORRECTLY. Curly braces are important, you can't just throw them wherever you want.

Comment: changed the code (see above), i get no errors, but now whenever "login" is clicked in the app, it always says the username or password is invalid.

Comment: You need to try things on your own. Are you going to come here whenever anything doesn't work? From your questions, this is obviously the first time you even got this thing to compile. And you spent what, less than 7 minutes trying to make it work.

Comment: I am trying, this is very frustrating. As i refresh the page i am switching things up and adding a subtracting code. i know it wont magically fix itself, i just want to understand why in-case i encounter this again.

Comment: So spend more than 7 minutes trying to debug.

Comment: ok, i did it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558959/android-simple-login-screen-crashes-app-when-logging-no-errors-in-eclipse-which

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

private EditText UserName;
private EditText Password;
private Button login;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
    UserName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    Password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String uName = UserName.getText().toString();
            String pWord = Password.getText().toString();
            if(uName.equals("test") && pWord.equals("test"))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Yup", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }
    );


}
```

}

Comment: changed the code (see above), i get no errors, but now whenever "login" is clicked in the app, it always says the username or password is invalid.